# MySQL "insert.... where not exists" is coming up all errors

Tags: mysql

This works:

```
insert into answers 
    (survey,user,answer)
    values(1,'hi',1)
;
```

This works:

```
select * from answers where survey=1 and user='hi';
```

This doesn't work:

```
insert
    into answers 
    (survey,user,answer)
    values(1,'hi',1)
    where not exists (select * from answers where survey=1 and user='hi')
;
```

It gives me an error 1064 right around the "where not exists" clause. I've looked up all the documentation I can find, but I can't find anything wrong with it.

Thoughts?

Comment: Please show us the exact error it gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `insert . . . select`, but not `insert . . . values`:

```
insert into answers(survey, user, answer)
    select survey, user, answer
    from (select 1 as survey, 'hi' as user, 1 as answer) s
    where not exists (select 1 from answers a where a.survey= s.survey and a.user = s.user);
```

That said, I would advise you to make `answer(survey, user)` either a unique or primary key, so the database enforces the uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for the `INSERT` statement in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) has no "where not exists".

What you probably want is `INSERT IGNORE INTO answers (survey,user,answer) values(1,'hi',1)`. This inserts the values unless it clashes with a primary or unique key on the table, in which case the values are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...` notation doesn't support a `WHERE` clause. Instead, you need to use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` notation, where you specify an actual query to generate the rows to insert. That query can, of course, contain a `WHERE` clause:

```
insert
    into answers 
    (survey,user,answer)
    select 1,'hi',1
    from (select 1)
    where not exists (select * from answers where survey=1 and user='hi')
;
```